# How to limit the resources on PySpark cluster for Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I want to restrict the usage of resources for my PySpark code running on Jupyter Notebook.
I tried

```
%%configure -f {'driverMemory': '1000M', "executorMemory": "2000M", "executorCores": 1, 'numExecutors': 10}
```

But it's throwing the following error:

> UsageError: %%configure is a cell magic, but the cell body is empty.

What does this error mean and how do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the settings in a new line, otherwise Jupyter can't find anything in the cell. Also avoid mixing single and double quotes.

```
%%configure -f
{
    "driverMemory": "1000M",
    "executorMemory": "2000M",
    "executorCores": 1,
    "numExecutors": 10
}
```

Comment: but I am using AWS EMR instance, and I need to change the config from the jupyter notebook itself. 

also hitting %%help in a cell on jupyter notebook shows that this can be done from the notebook itself.

Comment: @n0obcoder try edited answer? you need to put it in a new line.

Comment: that didnt work either. The error is- Could not parse JSON object from input '{'driverMemory': '1000M', "executorMemory": "2000M", "executorCores": 1, 'numExecutors': 10}
'

Comment: wow, it worked! : D but why this one work? Can you please explain the reason to me?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect it can't handle mixed single and double quotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226125/discussion-between-n0obcoder-and-mck).

Answer (score 3):

what you need is:

1. Create a spark session
2. Set the configuration
   Be carefull your configuration cannot pass your real spark cluster VMs configurations (While creating the cluster in AWS)

```
spark_session  = SparkSession.builder.\
                              .getOrCreate()
#You dont need to set the master IP
# adress since you are running the
# spark from the notebook as a client in the EMR 


spark_session.conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '2000M')
spark_session.conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '1')
spark_session.conf.set('spark.executor.instances', '10')
spark_session.conf.set('spark.driver.memory','1000M')
```

Then use the spark_session for your processing